# Docker Flask App connected to Docker DB not loading up in browser

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask App running in 1 docker container and postgres database in another Docker container. I'm trying to build and run these containers using docker-compose up --build. But when I try opening the 'Running On ' in my browser, the Flask app is not loading.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.0"

services:
  app:
    build: ./<app directory with Dockerfile>/
    networks:
      - my_conn
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  db:
    build: ./<Database directory with Dockerfile>/
    networks:
      - my_conn
    restart: always

networks:
  my_conn:
    driver: bridge
```

App Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /<docker-dir>
RUN pip install flask flask-sqlalchemy psycopg2
COPY ./<app directory> ./<app directory>
CMD ["python", "./<app directory>/app.py"]
```

DB Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
ENV POSTGRES_USER=username
ENV POSTGRES_DB=database
COPY initial_setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial_setup.sql
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)

url = "postgresql://username:secret@db:5432/database"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = url

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
engine = db.create_engine(url, {})

@app.route('/')
def index():
    with engine.connect() as eng:
        try:
            num = eng.execute(f"DELETE * FROM {table_name};")
            eng.commit()
        except:
            eng.rollback()
    return render_template('index.html', message=f'Rows deleted: {num}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

So far, what I've tried are:
app.py ->

```
.
.
.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
    # another attempt with
    # app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

app dockerfile ->

```
EXPOSE 5000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
app:
    build: ./<app directory with Dockerfile>/
    networks:
      - my_conn
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5000
```

and

```
app:
    build: ./<app directory with Dockerfile>/
    networks:
      - my_conn
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:5000:5000' # '127.0.0.1::5000'
```

and

```
app:
    build: ./<app directory with Dockerfile>/
    networks:
      - my_conn
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  db:
    build: ./<Database directory with Dockerfile>/
    networks:
      - my_conn
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. If someone can please check and point out what I can do to have my Flask app from Docker container load up on the port it runs on when the container gets build, and stay connected with the DB in other docker container. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: try remove the port in db ur
`
url = "postgresql://username:secret@db/database"
`

Comment: did not work. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

your docker-compose requires updates:

- upgrade service to 3
- add depends_on flag to app service

in your code, the db URL should be without port

your docker-compose file should be like

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  app:
    build: ./<app directory with Dockerfile>/
    networks:
      - my_conn
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  db:
    build: ./<Database directory with Dockerfile>/
    networks:
      - my_conn
    restart: always

networks:
  my_conn:
    driver: bridge
```